# Javascript: how to read a value from a json file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am a beginner in Javascript. I hope to get some help.

I built a local server using MAMP, and all my files are local. I want to read a value from a json file. This json file(data.json) has only one item `{"type":2}`, and I only want to use the value(2 in this case). But the value of "type" changes, so Javascript should read it constantly and maybe save it into a var in Javascript.

Can I listen for changes to that file so that I can be sure I always have the most up to date value for type?

I am still not familiar with Javascript. I would really appreciate it if you could give me some specific codes or examples.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: OP tagged jQuery, this is probably what you are looking for Rinko: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: "so Javascript should read it constantly " >> reading a file over and over is never a good idea, can´t you just read it when it gets changed?

Comment: Can include `js` at question ?

Comment: Hi! I was looking up the jQuery.getJSON( ) function. But I'm not sure if I can use it. I am not familiar with jQuery either.

Comment: Hi Juvian! Thanks for your advice. It is absolutely better than reading it over and over. I don't know how to do it yet, but I will look it up. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//Either

var json = {test:"test"};

console.log(json);

//Access JSON

console.log(json.test);

//Or

$.getJSON( "test.json", function( data ) {
  
  //Assign the json to your JSON variable
  json = data;
  
});

console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is JSON just a javascript object without functions, syntactically?
That is could't we have used your json example as regular js objects?

Comment: JSON is a data exchange format originally derived from JS Object Notation, which is why var json = {test:"test"}; The data types available are string, number, objects, arrays, boolean and null. JSON objects are decoded into objects in all sorts of languages. http://json.org/

Comment: Thank you so much Roberto! I tired the getJSON function because I want to read the value from a json file. Sorry for asking stupid question, but it shows 'Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined' in the console. I understand I need to define the variable first, but would you please show me what is the right way to do it here? Thank you so much.

Comment: just place var json = {}; before the $.getJSON... line. Watch out for the scope though.

Comment: Thanks! Now it returned Object {}. It seems like the data in the json file isn't successfully assigned to the variable. Do you have any suggestion for that?

Comment: Maybe it is not in a correct format. Care adding the JSON? you can check format in websites like jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com or https://www.jsoneditoronline.org

Comment: {"type": 2} This is what in my json file. It works in the formatter website. Sorry for keeping asking questions, but I cannot figure out it by myself...This is the full code: http://www.codeshare.io/s5s00  and the data.json is in the same folder. Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

JSON can come from anywhere, inbuilt into jquery is parseJSON which will return the json input string as a javascript object.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

```
var obj = $.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

where the json can come from anywhere.. an ajax call or where ever else.

```
$.ajax({
  url:'some url',
  data: someobject,
  type: 'get',
  success: function( responseFromServer ){
     var obj = $.parseJSON( responseFromServer  );
     alert( obj.name === "John" );
  }
});
```